# Squid deny_info https not working

Tags: centos, proxy, squid, squidguard

I have squid proxy server configured on centos 8 and working fine i have blocked some sites through squid when anyone access to blocked url it simply show the page browser cant open the page. I just want to ERROR_ACCESS. here is below my configuration.

```
acl localnet src 200.200.200.0/24
acl localnet src 172.30.0.0/16

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

http_access deny !Safe_ports

http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager

acl badsite url_regex "/etc/squid/block"
http_access deny badsite all
deny_info ERR_ACCESS_DENIED badsite

http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost

http_access deny all

http_port 3128
cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 100 16 256

coredump_dir /var/spool/squid

refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern (Release|Packages(.gz)*)$      0       20%     2880
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add the below in your `squid.conf`. This should resolve the issue

```
error_directory /usr/share/squid/errors/en/
deny_info ERR_ACCESS_DENIED badsite
```

[image: Screenshot of error_directory contents]